# Is it okay to store these data in local storage as long as I properly validate everything in the backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm doing a project to learn full stack development using MERN stack. I'm using jwt token for authentication. Here is what I sent to the client and store it on local storage when I login

username: migo

isAdmin: true

token: jwtToken

email: blabla@gmail.com

I thought that I should only store the token on localstorage and decode it to get isAdmin, username, email, etc. What is the proper way to handle that? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local storage should only contain data that is not sensitive, and that is not used to access your backend. Thus, I would say that you're safe to store information like `isAdmin` or `username` in the local storage. (Note that flags such as `isAdmin` should only be used for non-security purposes. E.g., to show a different user icon, theme, or maybe menu options)

If you have an option to store the JWT access token in an HTTP-only, secure cookie, then you should go with this solution. Nowadays it's not recommended to store tokens in local storage, as they're vulnerable to XSS attacks there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can save only the JWT web token on the browser's local storage and decode it on the backend/server side. But while sending the JWT as a response to frontend, make its property **httpOnly:true** for much better security so no 3rd person can access the JWT token

You can refer the below link for example

https://iditect.com/article/express-uses-jwt-and-httponly-cookie-for-security-verification.html